# JS add on to function instead of replace with prototype

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
base = {
    init : function() {
        console.log('initiate')
    }
}

function Plugin(){
    this.init = function() {
        console.log('init me');
    }
}

Plugin.prototype = base;

x = new Plugin();

x.init();
```

I want it to console log both, I want to be able to set a default set of functions as in base variable and add on to them in function Plugin.

https://jsfiddle.net/eqzwbdww/

Comment: You want `x.init()` to call both the own and inherited methods?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but solved it:

```
base = {
    init : function() {
       console.log('initiate')
    }
}

function Plugin(){
    this.init = function() {
       Plugin.prototype.init.call(this);
       console.log('init me');
    }
}

Plugin.prototype = base;

x = new Plugin();

x.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution, also not sure if this is the best one.

```js
base = {
    init : function() {

        document.write(' initiate ')
    }
}

function Plugin(){
    this.init = function() {
     this.__proto__.init ();
        document.write(' init me ');
    }
}
Plugin.prototype = base;

x = new Plugin();

x.init();
```